# How to get the PK_ID of the last inserted row in oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a scenario where I have to return the pkId of the row which is inserted into the db recently. But i am afraid there is no straight way to achieve it in Oracle. Can any one tell any way to do it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming 10g+, use the `RETURNING` clause:

```
INSERT INTO YOUR_TABLE
  (columns...)
VALUES
  (...)
RETURNING <expression> INTO <variables>
```

For more info, see:

- http://www.lattimore.id.au/2006/04/06/oracle-returning-clause/
- http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/misc/dml_returning_into_clause.php